# How can I suggest that Documentation tag be merged with another?

Tags: discussion, support, documentation

In the documentation section, there are 2 tags that are almost the same.

- playframework (11 topics)
- playframework-2.0 (1 topic)

In the question section of Stack Overflow, it makes a little more sense since there was a somewhat radical change between Play 1.X and 2.X but even in there, most people want help about the Play Framework in general and they specify the version in the question. I don't think that the version should be in the tag itself.

But in the documentation section of Stack Overflow, I'm pretty sure we want to keep only "playframework". Or in the worst scenario, we could have "playFramework-1.0-legacy" and the main one would be called "playframework".

So how can I suggest this to be merged? Or is there an admin here that can suggest the change?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Post on Meta tagged [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)[documentation](/questions/tagged/documentation)[merge-request](/questions/tagged/merge-request). You can use this question if you want :)

Comment: I've updated my question. Merge-request doesn't exist. :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCôté huh. I thought it did.

Comment: I think [retag-request](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/retag-request) fits because merging two Documentation tags is essentially moving all topics of one tag to another tag.